# Expo icons height

Tags: react-native, expo

I use expo icons in my app, and when I increase the size of the icon its width and height are both increases. I need to increase the icon's height only, any suggestion for that?

```
 import { Entypo } from "@expo/vector-icons";

<Entypo name="bookmark" size={30} color="black" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking of two solutions for this as follows:

1. I think it renders the icon as the `svg` tag so that you can have a CSS class to custom the height of the icon.

```
// File.jsx
import './icon.css'
...
<span className='icon-size'>
   <Entypo name="bookmark" color="black" />
</span>
```

```
// icon.css
.icon-size svg { height: 30px; }
```

2. You can use the `style` attribute in the tag.

```
<Entypo name="bookmark" color="black" style={{ height: 30 }} />
```

Comment: the first solution, Entypo doesn't have className prop. the second solution, style prop for the container.

Comment: Oops sorry, I was wrong in the first one, I edited it. So, it supposed to be contained in a `span` and you can use CSS to custom the svg in the span.